# How do I write a query that request multiple items from an array?

Tags: couchdb

Here is an example document:

```
{
    "_id": "7d7db310ff3acc857c7f301f67979de5",
    "_rev": "1-3ed97634540c35292155ad40b99cafc1",
    "interests": [
        "cats",
        "dogs",
        "fish",
        "reptiles"
    ],
    "gender": "male",
    "phone": "716-555-0111"
}
```

I'd like a query that would look for multiple items in an array.

For example, say I wanted a list of people who have both "cats" AND "dogs" listed under "interests."

Answer (score 1):

You could create a simple view, for example "by_interests" with map function

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.interests)
   doc.interests.forEach(function(interest){
     emit(interest, doc)
   })
}
```

And then query results

http://localhost:5984/db_name/_design/_desgin_name/_view/by_interests?keys=[%22cats%22,%22dogs%22]

Comment: I gave this a try in a temporary view, and I got the following error: Expression does not eval to a function. (function(doc) {
 if (doc.interests) 
  doc.interests.forEach(function(interest){
   emit(interest, doc})
 }
})

Comment: thanks, the script works, but it works like an "OR" instead of an "AND", that is if a person likes cats but not dogs, they still show up in the list

Answer (score -1):

You could create a secondary index which includes only the documents containing cats and dogs.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are getting at. Are you referring to something within the document? In which case, that is does not help. If you are referring to creating something within the query, I'm not sure how to go about doing it.